# How can I get a left-navigation column to fill the entire left side of the middle of a webpage using CSS?

Tags: css

I'm working on making this web page:

http://jsfiddle.net/pW8yj/

and I want to get a left navigation area to extend all the way down the left side, from the bottom of the header to the top of the footer. I tried setting height: 100% but that didn't seem to work. Is there something I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Here's what I got after spending 2.143 seconds to search Google: http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/equal-height-columns-cross-browser-css-no-hacks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will never work the way you're expecting it to.  You cannot set a 100% height to the element as it will go to 100% of its content, not the height of its parent container.

What I recommend doing is removing the background from the leftNAv area, and instead, set a repeating background on div id="middleArea" with the grey part as repeat-y.  that way, no matter how big the #middleArea gets, the background will expand regardless.

You can try resources like Faux Columns which may give you the templates and other results you're looking for:

http://www.code-sucks.com/css%20layouts/faux-css-layouts/

Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

change your CSS, position the left side absolute, and position your content area left margin to be equal to the width you specified for left area

```
#middleArea { 

}

#leftArea { 
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 150px;
    height: 80%;
    background-color: gray;
    position: absolute;
}

#contentArea { 
    vertical-align: top;
    margin: 30px 30px 30px 150px;
    border: 1px dotted orange;
    width: 600px;
    display: block;
    border: 1px solid black;

}
```